# Discord - Picking from lists in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm making a discord bot. I have a command called love. I want it to pick a random quote from a list, but I am unsure how to do this.
Here is what I have so far:

```
if (message.content === config.prefix + "love" ) {
    message.reply(LoveRnd());
}

function LoveRnd(){
    var items = items["test1","test2","test3"];
    var rnd = math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
    var output = items[rnd];
    return output;
}
```

Comment: [a chat bot](https://botlist.co/bots/filter?category=&platform=15)?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how you'd do it:

Make a Quotes array:

```
const quotes = ["test1","test2","test3"]
```

Let's now come to your function:

```
const loveRnd = () => quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]
```

So what are we doing?

We're multiplying a random number (Math.random()) by the length of your quotes array and flooring that up, so that the value returned is not greater than the indexes your array has.

This function gives a random value out of the array of quotes which is defined above.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were going for? I just fixed a couple of typos

```
function LoveRnd(){
  var items = ["test1","test2","test3"];
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
  var output = items[rnd];
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
function LoveRnd(){
    var items = ["test1","test2","test3"];
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
    var output = items[rnd];
    return output;
}
```

your first math miss the M Cap
and your list does not need the 2nd 'items'

Answer (score -1):

Have a function which picks a random index from available list.

```
    var globalIndex = 1;
    function pickRandom(index, min, max) {
       return (index * 7 % (max - min + 1);
    }

    function chooseRandomQuote(quotes) {
       return quotes[pickRandom(globalIndex++, 0, quotes.length)];
    }
```

pickRandom() function will always produce the number between 0 and quotes.length. e.g. You can try globalIndex = 30, then pickRandom() will produce the number for 0 to 10 (length of quotes) as 210%11 = 1.

EDIT:
I just made the globalIndex not easily predictable.

```
var prime1 = 7;
 var prime2 = 23;
 var globalIndex = prime2;

 function pickRandom(min, max) {

      var randNum = ((globalIndex * prime1) % (max - min + 1));
      globalIndex = prime2 * randNum;
      return randNum;
  }

 function chooseRandomQuote(quotes) {
     return quotes[pickRandom(0, quotes.length)];
 }
```

You can choose any two prime numbers here prime1 and prime2.

For reference: https://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/build-your-own-simple-random-numbers/

Comment: For your example use the following in  function LoveRnd(){
     var items = items["test1","test2","test3"];
     return chooseRandomQuote(items);}

Comment: This doesn't pick a **random** index. It picks an index. If `chooseRandomQuote` is the only function that uses `globalIndex`, there is a well-defined and predictable order in which quotes are returned.

Comment: You can make use of Math.random() to pick globalIndex. I used this variable and incrementing it by 1 just as an example.

Comment: you named your method "pickRandom" even though it does not pick randomly - given the same input, repeatedly calling the function can never yield a different answer. That is a bad name for the method.

Comment: You are right. My bad. I just made some correction please have a look. This might help.